# Error causing many warnings and an error within Eclipse Java Project

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, compiler-errors

I'm working on a Java project within the following environment:

Eclipse Kepler 
JDK 1.7.0_60
Java 1.7
Uses SVN

The project seemingly runs as expected, yet an error still persists.

Eclipse gives me the following when I check it:

```
%dbnotn -> %dbnotn -> %dbnotn),
```

The error is located within an xml file with test data that is not currently being used.  The most odd part is, if I put in a bunch of line breaks near the error, the error will just continue to move up to the next line in the file.  If I delete the current line with an error, again, the error just moves up to the next line in the file.

Since no one else is having issues with this particular file, and the number of warnings I have is about 15x more than any other person working on the project, it leads me to believe that something is wrong with my preferences, jdk, or some mystery setting.

Has anyone else had an issue similar to this? If not, any suggestions as to what could be the problem?

Is it possible that when I imported the project from SVN that there was some issue?

Comment: "gives me the following when I check it" - What do you "check"? How do you do it? Which tool/plugin/... generates the error message?

Comment: Just in the general 'Problems' tab within Eclipse, a "description" if you will, is given for every error that exists.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. This strange error appears in my xml file (docbook xml to be precise).  'Problems' tab within Eclipse gives the same stupid description %dbnotn -> %dbnotn -> %dbnotn),